# Run python script return exit code =1 as service Ubuntu

Tags: scripts, python, systemd, services

I create a file job_tracking.py

```
#!/home/thao/venv/bin/python
while True:
    print("hello")
    # job_tracking_stats()
    log_app('Stats tracking Sleeping...')
    time.sleep(5)
    log_app('Stats tracking Wakeup...')
```

and a job_tracking.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Test Service
After=multi-user.target
Conflicts=getty@tty1.service

[Service]
Type=simple
User=thao
ExecStart=/home/thao/venv/bin/python /home/thao/vodjs/job_tracking.py
StandardInput=tty-force

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I follow this tutorial https://websofttechs.com/tutorials/how-to-setup-python-script-autorun-in-ubuntu-18-04/

But when i check my status service it return

```
Thg 12 15 11:42:50 thao-HP-ZBook-15 systemd[1]: Started Test Service.
Thg 12 15 11:42:50 thao-HP-ZBook-15 systemd[1]: job_tracking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Thg 12 15 11:42:50 thao-HP-ZBook-15 systemd[1]: job_tracking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

What did i wrong?
Edit: my script require a folder `/home/thao/logs` when i run in terminal, i dont know which folder is require when run in systemd.
This is log_app function:

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

log_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s: %(message)s', datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

logFile = './logs/app.log'
log_handler = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(logFile, when="D", interval=1, backupCount=0)
log_handler.setFormatter(log_formatter)
log_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

app_log = logging.getLogger('P2P')
app_log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
app_log.addHandler(log_handler)



def log_app(string):
    #In ra bien string trong file log duoi LEVEL INFO
    app_log.info(string)
    print(string)
```

Comment: Is this the entire script?

Comment: it return `Thg 12 15 11:54:10 thao-HP-ZBook-15 systemd[8083]: job_tracking.service: Failed to execute command: No such file or directory
Thg 12 15 11:54:10 thao-HP-ZBook-15 systemd[8083]: job_tracking.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /home/thao/vodjs/job_tracking.py: No such file or directory
`when i remove `/home/thao/venv/bin/python` as you said.  My code run well when i run in terminal with same ExecStart

Comment: my script require a folder /home/thao/logs when i run in terminal, i dont know which folder is require when run in systemd

Comment: Is this a user or system service? What are the permissions on `/home/thao/logs`?

Comment: I dont know, Do you have any tutorial ? folder `/home/thao/logs` i just created by mkdir.

Comment: I just follow that tututorial in above

Comment: Your Python script is not indented properly.

Comment: I'm sorry, it is just format of this website. My code work well in terminal before i run it as service

Comment: I found my problem is `logFile = './logs/app.log'` , i will change to fixed direction. I thougtht it because of config in ubuntu. But i wrong, anyway thanks all